# How to get the opposite value of a bool variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables, boolean

To me, a bool variable indicates either **true** or **false**.

Some bool variable was defined and initialized to a value unknown to us. I just want to get the opposite value of it. How should I do it in C++?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just use the `!` operator:

```
bool x = // something

bool y = !x;  //  Get the opposite.
```

Answer (score 18):

```
bool b = false;
```

---

Correct solution:

```
b = !b;
```

Interesting solutions that you should not use:

```
b = b?false:true;
b ^= 1;
b = (b+1)%2;
b = 1>>b;
b = 1-b;
b = b-1;
b = -1*(b-1);
b = b+'0'+'1'-'b';
```

As an exercise, try to figure out why the above solutions work.

Comment: +1 for creative answer with appropriate warning, but I wouldn't have written that with C style casts, I'm not even sure you need the casts, for example `b=1-b` the RHS gets promoted automatically

Comment: @awoodland: Thanks. I removed the casts. I was thinking in terms of casting so I put them in but of course they are unnecessary.

Comment: your first solution was the first one that came to my mind :)

Answer (score 11):

#### OPERATORS for logical Not

You can choose whether you want to write **`!`**, or **`not`**, or some mixture.

However, still as of version 10.0 Visual C++ does not have the reserved word `not` built-in.

So for Visual C++, if you want to use `not` you have to include the [**iso646.h**] header, which is a header from the standard C library, guaranteed to be available also in C++. However, for a standard-compliant C++ compiler including that header has no effect (as noted in footnote 176 of the C++11 standard). So you can just include it anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iso646.h>  // Visual C++ is not quite standard and requires this.

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    
    // Display false and true as "false" and "true":
    cout << boolalpha;
    
    cout << "!false = " << !false << endl;
    cout << "not false = " << not false << endl;
}
```

---

#### About COMPARING boolean values:

Some novices write things like

```
    v != true
```

That's not just verbose but a downright *dangerous* habit. The reason that it’s dangerous is that many APIs define boolean types where the possible values are not restricted to just 0 and 1 (a prime example is Window’s `BOOL` type). Then a value can denote logical True while not being numerically equal to True.

So, for maximum safety, make it a habit to use `!` or `not`, and just *never* compare directly to a literal boolean value.

An example where it is generally necessary to compare boolean values is where you need logical Xor (exclusive or, either-or). C++ lacks an operator for that at the `bool` level. But you can write `a != b` to achieve the same as a hypothetical `bool`-level Xor operator would have.

---

#### Logical Xor as a CONTROLLED INVERSION

In some cases you want an inversion (application of logical Not) if some condition is true, like …

```
    if( condition )
    {
        x = !x;
    }
```

This can alternatively be written as …

```
    x = ((condition) != x);
```

It looks like total obfuscation, but it has two features that can be handy in certain situations:

- it can be used as a kind of “masked” inversion for an array `a` of values, with the values of some other array serving to control whether each element of `a` is inverted, and
- it is a pure expression computation that does not involve a choice of execution path, and thus it can conceivably be used as an optimization (however, I gather that a modern compiler is likely to do this for you at the machine code level, if it is appropriate to do).

Comment: didn't know about being able to use `not` as a keyword. Nice stuff Alf

Answer (score 9):

You want the NOT operator, which is `!` in C, C++ and many other related languages.

```
bool t = true;
bool f = !t;    // f = false
```

Answer (score 5):

Given `bool value;` having been set appropriately:

You should use for this:

```
  !value
```

where `!` is logical not here.

In addition there are a number of other ways of achieving the same effect, which are all effectively obfuscation:

1. `std::not_equal_to<bool>()(true,value);` (requires `#include <functional>`)
2. `std::count(&value, &value+1, false);` (requires `#include <algorithm>`)
3. `std::count_if(&value,&value+1,std::not1(std::bind2nd(std::greater_equal<bool>(), true)));`

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the not operator that way it will give you the opposite

```
    !
```

this should give you what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool opposite = (someboolvar) ? 0 : 1 ;
```

Comment: wonder why people downvote on this one, which seems correct to me.

Comment: @paul - it might be like this to get around the short answer filter perhaps?

Comment: Don't use a complicated operator when a simple one (`!`) will do. Your future maintainers will stare at the code wondering what it's really supposed to do without realizing it's correct as it stands.

Comment: @terry - it works, but it's hard to see the use of the ternary operator like this as anything but obfuscation.

Comment: @Paul Everyone beat me to the real answer, so I decided to post an alternative. 
**By the way**, If I find someone from my company staring at this code and wondering what it does, the person can go hunting for a new job.

Comment: This answer is as appropriate as the question.

Comment: If the idea is just to produce something that's different from the correct answer whilst still producing the correct result, I vote `bool opposite = (someboolvar == false);`

Comment: I'm wondering whether I dislike the `?:` or the `0:1` instead of `false:true` more.